# How to set arcpy code that do not automatic add to display completed layers when batch a seriels raster/shp?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

Maybe this is a small question.But I can't find any set method. When using arcpy to batch in arcmap, it automatic add the operated raster/shp files to new data layers. how to close it ? the set is in arcmap or in arcpy codes? I just want to carry out data using arcmap. When it loads data to a new layer, it causes routine slowly.

Comment: How are you implementing the Python `arcpy` module?

Comment: yes.Python `arcpy` module apply in arcmap(desktop)@Aaron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running scripts from the Python interpreter in ArcMap, you need to turn off the "Add results of the geoprocessing operations to the display" option located in Geoprocessing > Geoprocessing Options...

You may prefer to run scripts through your favorite IDE such as IDLE or PyScripter, in which case, the results will never be added to the display unless you specify it.

[image]

Comment: All right! could the `arcpy` be carried out without lauching arcmap?

Comment: Yes, simply use `import arcpy` in your script.